How to save a webauthn passkey in jdbc database?
With the latest Spring-Security version (6.4.0-RC1) it is now possible to register passkeys and log in with them. You can simply implement them by configuring the SecurityConfig.java as described here.
@Bean
SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) {
    http
        // ...
        .formLogin(withDefaults())
        .webAuthn((webAuthn) -> webAuthn
            .rpName("Spring Security Relying Party")
            .rpId("example.com")
            .allowedOrigins("https://example.com")
        );
    return http.build();
}

@Bean
UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
    UserDetails userDetails = User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
        .username("user")
        .password("password")
        .roles("USER")
        .build();

    return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(userDetails);
}

You can login ("user"+"password") and register a passkey on localhost:8080/webauthn/register. After a logout localhost:8080/logout it is possible to login with the created passkey.
However, I can't manage to save this passkey persistently so that the login also works after a restart of the application.
I noticed that MapUserCredentialsRepository.java (org.springframework.security.web.webauthn.management) gets invoked to save a CredentialRecord.
@Override
public void save(CredentialRecord credentialRecord) {
    Assert.notNull(credentialRecord, "credentialRecord cannot be null");
    this.credentialIdToUserCredential.put(credentialRecord.getCredentialId(), credentialRecord);
    this.userEntityIdToUserCredentialIds
        .computeIfAbsent(credentialRecord.getUserEntityUserId(), (id) -> new HashSet<>())
        .add(credentialRecord.getCredentialId());
    }

A CredentialRecord contains relevant fields like credentialId, publicKey, signatureCount, label and more.
I think that the CredentialRecord.java (org.springframework.security.web.webauthn.api) has to be saved but I am not sure how and if that is true. The JavaDoc of CredentialRecord.java:
/**
 * Represents a <a href="https://www.w3.org/TR/webauthn-3/#credential-record">Credential
 * Record</a> that is stored by the Relying Party
 * <a href="https://www.w3.org/TR/webauthn-3/#reg-ceremony-store-credential-record">after
 * successful registration</a>.
 *
 * @author Rob Winch
 * @since 6.4
 */
public interface CredentialRecord {


YOu need to create a JDBC implementation of the PublicKeyCredentialUserEntityRepository and UserCredentialRepository interfaces. Register them as beans and they will be automatically picked up and used.

Thank you @m-deinum for your quick reply! Here’s how I understood your answer:
Create a JdbcUserCredentialRepositoryclass that implements UserCredentialRepositoryand has a private final JdbcTemplate.
Then, create a Bean in my SecurityConfig.java:
@Bean public JdbcUserCredentialRepository jdbcUserCredentialRepository(JdbcTemplate jdbcT) {return new JdbcUserCredentialRepository(jdbcT);} Repeat the same process for JdbcPublicKeyCredentialUserEntityRepository.
Is this correct? Do I need to create any additional classes? I hope you can help me with this beginner question.

That is more or less it. You could also use it with @Repository instead of creating an @Bean method. Either will work.

Thank you @M.Deinum - I still did not manage to implement it but I am thankful for your direction. Do you think that is the best/easiest way to save passkeys? I probably need to look more into Spring Data/JPA/JDBC, but for now I would appreciate an answer: Are further classes necessary such as a CredentialRecord.java to save passkeys?

CredentialRecord is part of the API you don't need to implement that. YOu need just an implementation that uses the storage of your choice that saves that in some representation and converts the representation into  a CredentialRecord again.
